# how to use open dft in 2d vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to ask how to use the dft function in opencv to do Fourier transform with 2d vector.

I have error in my code ...

thank you all

```
    //2d vector in here v1 and v2 
    //vector size is 1000*1000
    //i have to do about 600 images in this process 
    for (int k = 0; k < 600; k++){
        vector <vector <complex < double >>> v1(InputWidth, vector<complex < double >>(InputHeight));
        vector <vector <complex < double >>> v2(InputWidth, vector<complex < double >>(InputHeight));
        for (int i = 0; i < InputWidth; i++) {
            int tempIndex = i*InputHeight;
            for (int j = 0; j < InputHeight; j++)
            {
                int Correction_value = ProjectionImage[k]->data.s[tempIndex + j] * meshGrid[tempIndex + j];
                ProjectionImage[k]->data.s[tempIndex + j] = Correction_value;
                //v1 is an image
                v1[i][j] = Correction_value;
            }
        }
        //error happen in here
        dft(v1, v2, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
        //do frequency filter
        for (int i = 0; i < InputWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < InputHeight; j++)
            {
                v2[i][j] *= filter_2D[i][j];
            }
        }
        //inverse fourier transform
        idft(v2, v1, DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
   }
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7qHK.png)

Comment: Please don't store your images that way. If you are using OpenCV, copy your data to a `cv::Mat`.

Comment: Not to mention you'll be able to take advantage of vectorized operations OpenCV provides, instead of all those nested loops (and probably improve performance to boot).

Comment: DO NOT post the error as an image, copy it as text and translate it to english.... Do not use vector of vectors of types that are not possible (as far as I know) in OpenCV, and use always cv::Mat. Finally, googling you get a tutorial that actually uses complex numbers and everything... [here it is](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you create a `std::vector` of pointers to other vectors. Those other vectors contain the pixel data. But those data are therefore not necessarily contiguous. Each row (or column) of your image is stored in its own memory segment. OpenCV expects all pixels to be in the same memory segment.

In short, simply copy your pixel data to a form supported by OpenCV, such as a `cv::Mat`.